# Trying to get data from api and map to another component in React

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to map an array of movies which I get from an API.

The data is fetched successfully but when I try to map the values and display, it becomes `undefined` and does not show anything.

I'm new to React so any help and advice would be helpful.

```js
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

const getMovieData = () => {
  axios
    .get(api_url)
    .then((response) => {
      const allMovies = response.data;
      console.log(allMovies);
      setItems(allMovies);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
};

useEffect(() => {
  getMovieData();
}, []);

return (
  <div>
    {items.map((item) => {
      <p>{item.title}</p>;
    })}
  </div>
);
```

The data is stored like this:

```
0: {
  adult: false, 
  backdrop_path: '/9eAn20y26wtB3aet7w9lHjuSgZ3.jpg', 
  id: 507086, 
  title: 'Jurassic World Dominion', 
  original_language: 'en',
  ...
}
```

Comment: It's normal. You need to learn about promises in Javascript. Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise. I will write a full answer.

Comment: use lazy load best option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your **items** value is an empty array`[]` as you have initialized with `setState([])` and your `useEffect()` runs only after your component is rendered which means even before you could do your data fetching, your HTML is being displayed inside which you are trying to get `{item.title}` where your **items** is an **empty array** currently and hence undefined. You will face this issue often as you learn along. So if you want to populate paragraph tag with `item.title` you should fast check if your **items** is an empty array or not and only after that you can do the mapping as follow and also you need to return the element from the map callback. If it takes some time to fetch the data, you can choose to display a loading indicator as well.

```js
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const getMovieData = () => {
  axios.get(api_url)
    .then((response) => {
      const allMovies = response.data;
      console.log(allMovies);
      setItems(allMovies);
    }).catch(error => console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
};

useEffect(() => {
  getMovieData();
}, []);
return ( < div > {
    items.length !== 0 ? items.map((item) => {
      return <p > {
        item.title
      } < /p>
    }) : < LoadingComponent / >
  }

  <
  /div>
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not returning anything from your map

```
{ 
  items.map((item) => {
   // Add a return
   return <p>{item.title}</p>
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good catch by Ryan Zeelie, I did not see it.

Another thing, since you're using promises and waiting for data to retrieve, a good practice is to check if data is present before mapping.

Something like :

```js
return (
    <div>
         { (items.length === 0) ? <p>Loading...</p> :  items.map( (item)=>{
         <p>{item.title}</p>
         })}
    </div>
);
```

Basically, if the array is empty (data is not retrieved or data is empty), display a loading instead of mapping the empty array.

Comment: Yea good point! Additionally check the data being received, incase it comes back as undefined or null then the map will run and throw errors.

const allMovies = response?.data; if(allMovies) setItems(allMovies)